# is there a way to store a word file in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to store a word file in mysql server management studio 2005 and when i researched for it all the post said try using blob. But the problem i have now is that there is no blob data type. Is there any other way to store the word file or even if possible a replacement for a blob data type

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You didn't search really long. BLOB is short for "binary large object"
2. You either have MySQL or SQL Server 2005 (which has Management studio)

So, go ahead and do some more research :)

Maybe start [here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx)